# How do I find out if my cpu is affected by the intel memory leak?

Tags: intel, cpu, memory-leak

**info:** 
https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/01/02/intel_cpu_design_flaw/ 
https://libreboot.org/faq.html#intelme

My computer has an intel CPU but is pretty old, from 2007, maybe earlier, so I am holding out hope that it might not be affected by this, but how do I find out? I've got a few computers I want to check.
I've got system profiler and benchmark which tells me some things about my CPU but what am I looking for? What would indicate that my CPU has the hardware responsible for this memory leak?
Running: Ubuntu 16.04.3

Comment: Your two links does not reference the same issue. The second one is about Intel ME, which is a problem of its own, but unrelated to the recent kernel leaks.

Comment: See [here](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=x86-PTI-EPYC-Linux-4.15-Test). you can check with `cat /proc/cpuinfo`, if it reports `cpu_insecure` under "bugs", you're affected. Note that you need to be running a patched kernel for it to tell you (and to have the fix).

Comment: ran `cat /proc/cpuinfo` bugs: (nothing) there is a blank space after bugs, hope this is a good sign :)

Comment: i thought the two were the same thing really? intel ME being the door through which the memory leaks accessed? school me bro

Comment: @Joe it doesn't have anything to do with the Intel ME, you could completely disable it and this bug would still exist. The reason for this bug is Intel's processors performing speculative execution without security checks.

Comment: No, the blank space after bugs does not mean anything unless you have the very latest kernel / patched kernel - which will take a while to arrive in Ubuntu.  And at the moment, it seems that _all_ Intel CPUs are affected.

Answer (score 1):

The flaw appears to affect all 64-bit Intel CPUs. From the [article](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/01/02/intel_cpu_design_flaw/):

> the flaw is in the Intel x86-64 hardware

You can use

```
lscpu | awk 'NR==1 || NR==10 {print $NF;}'
```

or with `grep` as mentioned in the comments by Patrick Mezkev:

```
lscpu | grep -E "(Architecture|Vendor ID)"
```

to determine if your CPU is 64-bit (`x86_64`) and manufactured by Intel (`GenuineIntel`). If both of these are returned from that command, your CPU is affected.

Additionally, as mentioned by JonasCz, if you're running a patched kernel, you can check `/proc/cpuinfo` for `cpu_insecure`:

```
grep cpu_insecure /proc/cpuinfo
```

This is (as of the time of writing this post) quite worthless due to the following:

1. No patched kernel has arrived to Ubuntu.
2. All x86 CPUs are being marked as "vulnerable".

Comment: Or: `lscpu | grep -E "ˆ(Architecture|Vendor ID)"`

Comment: `grep cpu_insecure /proc/cpuinfo` doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: @Joe Hence the reason I prefaced it with "running a patched kernel", and you are almost certainly not given that no patches have arrived to Ubuntu yet. If you are not, it won't show up, regardless of whether you're affected by it or not.